# Buffer zone, binary exclusion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a shapefile of 20 cities in ArcMap 10.

I need to position a sheep farm so that it is not within 2 miles of any of these cities.

So, I created a buffer, with 2 miles as distance.

I used the polygon to raster tool.

Now, I need to make this raster so that all space within any of these circles is [0] and all space outside the circles is [1].

I’m not sure how to do this part! I’m new to ArcMap and have been using raster calculator, reclassify tools, no success however.

Comment: Why a raster? Vector works just fine unless you have a specific workflow you need to follow. Try setting your arcpy.env.extent to the full area of interest before doing polygon to raster, from here you can use IsNull to generate a binary raster which is 1 (more than 2 miles) and 0 (within 2 miles) provided you have a spatial analyst license (I assume you do as you're trying to do raster evaluation), if not create a big polygon in a new feature class, erase (advanced license required) the buffers from it or union with the buffer then rasterize the erased/union polygon.

Comment: @ Michael Stimson - Hi Michael, thanks for replying. Apologies, but what is the ‘IsNull’ function? Are you referring to the raster calculator here? You seem to suggest creating a binary raster? How should I do this? I do have the spatial analyst licience. I’m trying to create the map for a local community group. Tim.

Comment: I would prefer to use the raster calculator or reclassify tools wherever possible. Thank you.

Comment: IsNull can be used in the raster calculator https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000m8000000 the key is though to set your geoprocessing extent https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000009000000 to the size of your area of interest, that will give you lots of cells with 1 outside the cells with 0 where your buffers are by using IsNull on your existing raster generated from your polygons.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - Thanks. What formula should I input into the raster calculator, to produce a binary output raster where 0 means the sheep farm is situated within the buffer and 1 means it is not. Tim.

Answer (score 1):

[IsNull](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000m8000000) is in the raster calculator:

[image]

But before you hit **OK** set the environment [Output Extent](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000009000000) ([snap raster](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Snap_Raster/001w0000000m000000/) also helps with raster analysis):

[image]

[image]

So that your output image is big enough to exceed any area you would be looking in.